# Finding the stabilizer group given a state

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-information, group-theory

Consider general pure state
$|\psi\rangle$ 
in some hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (which could be a tensor product of other Hilbert spaces)

**I would like to know whether there is a way to  systematically find the group of all operators on $\mathcal{H}$ under which $|\psi\rangle$ is invariant.**

A little more precisely: the group I'm looking for is 
$$
G=\{A \in H(\mathcal{H}): A|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle\}
$$
Where $ H(\mathcal{H})$ is the set of Hermitian operators acting on the Hilbert space.

This group I defined here is a stabilizer group in the [usual sense in mathematics](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stabilizer.html), and a slight generalization of the [ones popularized by Gottesman in quantum information](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705052) as we're considering a general state.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): The set of self-adjoint operators on ${\cal H}$ is not closed under composition, and hence not a group. E.g. the product $\sigma_x\sigma_y$ is not self-adjoint but $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ are.

Comment: But I think if you work it out carefully, G will be a group.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "find"?  In a given situation, there might be a "simpler" or "more illuminating" characterization of the set you call $G$ than what you wrote, but how can one answer this question given that whether or not one characterization is "simpler" or "more illuminating" is subjective?  Perhaps you could clarify what form you would like the answer to take?

Comment: Say I have an explicit expression for $\psi$, where the Hilber space is finite, I want to explicitly write down every element in G.

Comment: You need to specify that you are talking about non-singular operators, otherwise there will be elements in $G$ with no inverse, so $G$ would not be a group. It is worth noticing, however, that this restriction would rule out things like the projection operators onto $|\psi\rangle$, but these operators are hugely important to quantum mechanics.

Comment: Neither it is an additive (abelian) group because the null element $0$ (operator zero) does not belong to $G$...could you specify the operations under which it becomes a group?

Comment: The group action is multiplication. Let me give an example used often in error correction: in a 2-particle spin system, the set $\{I,Z_1,Z_2,Z_1,Z_2\}$ where $Z_1$ is the pauli Z operator on the first particle, $Z_2$ is the same operator in the 2nd particle's Hilbert space, $Z_1Z_2$ is the tensor product of the two. As you can see it contains Identity I, each element has a inverse, and it is closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the problem is technically difficult due to the fact that generally unbounded self-adjoint operators like those used in general QM have domain smaller that the whole Hilbert space.

For this reason I will consider here only bounded self-adjoint operators whose domain, as is well known, is the full Hilbert space.

**Proposition**. *The elements of $G$ are all the operators of this form:*

$$A= P^\perp B P^\perp + P \tag{1}$$

*where*:

(i) $B=B^\dagger$ *is every **bounded self-adjoint** operator*

(ii) *$P$ is an orthogonal projector such that $P \geq |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$ (I am assuming that $|\psi\rangle$ has norm $1$) and $P^\perp := I -P$.* 
*(In other words $P$ is the orthogonal projector on a subspace including $|\psi\rangle$ and $P^\perp$ is the orthogonal projector on the orthogonal subspace to that space.)*

PROOF. If $A= P^\perp B P^\perp + P$ then $A|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$ by construction (notice that $P^\perp |\psi\rangle=0$) and $A= A^\dagger$ since $B,P,P^\perp$ are self-adjoint so that
$$A^\dagger= (P^\perp)^\dagger B^\dagger (P^\perp)^\dagger + P^\dagger
= P^\perp B P^\perp + P =A\:.$$
Conversely, if $A\in G$, as it is self-adjoint, let us consider its spectral decomposition:
$$A = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda dP^{(A)}(\lambda)\:.$$
As $1 \in \sigma_p(A)$, because $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, the spectral measure satisfies $P^{(A)}(\{ 1\}) \geq |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$ and the integral can be decomposed as:
$$A = \int_{\sigma(A)\setminus\{1\}} \lambda dP^{(A)}(\lambda)  + 1P^{(A)}(\{ 1\})\:.$$
where 
$$C := \int_{\sigma(A)\setminus\{1\}} \lambda dP^{(A)}(\lambda)$$
admits $(P^{(A)})^{\perp}(\cal H)$ as invariant space and vanishes on $P^{(A)}(\cal H)$, just for the additive property of the spectral measure $P^{(A)}$. Therefore, it holds, for $P:=P^{(A)}$,
$$P^\perp C P^\perp =C\:.$$
Defining $B:=C$ we have again, 
 $A= P^\perp B P^\perp + P$.

QED

Notice that, for every $A\in G$, there are many couples  $(B,P)$ associated to it via (1). However running $B$ throughout the real space of self-adjoint operators (1) and $P$ throughout the set of orthogonal projectors on subspaces including $|\psi\rangle$  reproduces all elements of $G$.

You also see that $G$ is not a group, *with the usual definition in math*, with respect to the composition of operators, because if $\cal H$ has sufficiently large dimension you can find two non-commuting elements of $G$ so that their product does not belong to $G$ as it is not self-adjoint. It is not a group eferhring to the sum of operators because $G$ does not include the null operator.

The problem with unbounded operators is that $BP^{\perp}$ may be undefined because the range of $P^\perp$ may not belong to the domain of $B$. However it is possible to re-arrange a similar construction if specifying some detail.

Comment: Does the reasoning work also if the multiplicity of $1$ is not one, i.e. if $P^{(A)}(\{1\})\supset P$? Very smart decomposition anyways...

Comment: Could you be more precise on this last question?

Comment: In general $P^{(A)}({1})$ may not be a rank one projection (if the multiplicity of the eigenvalue one is more than just one); so you do not have the equality $P^{(A)}({1})=P$, but just "inclusion" (ok that may not be very precise mathematically, sorry), in the sense that the range of $P$ is included in the range of $P^{(A)}({1})$. If $\phi\perp\psi$ is another normalized eigenvector corresponding to $1$, we would have $P^{(A)}({1})\phi=\phi$ but $P\phi=0$.

Comment: Another remark (and then I'm done I promise ;-)). In my opinion, if $B$ is a densely defined operator, and since $P$ is a rank one projection, $\{0\}\neq P^{\perp}D(B)\subseteq D(B)$ (equality attained if $\psi\notin D(B)$). So I don't think there would be domain problems with your construction if you consider only densely defined operators $B$ (and that seems very natural).

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying about $P^{(A)} \supset P$, but I do not understand your question :)  Regarding the second issue, well  there is no reason for having $P^\perp D(B) \subset D(B)$ even if $D(B)$ is dense and $P$ is rank one. $P^\perp D(B) \subset D(B)$ is evidently equivalent to $P D(B) \subset D(B)$ (because $P+P^\perp=I$ and $BI$ is always defined). Take $B=X$ position operator  $L^2(R)$ and $\psi(x) \sim 1/x$ for $|x| \to \infty$. If $P= |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$ then $PD(B) \not \subset D(B)$ is not defined.

Comment: However, my problem concerned $P^\perp({\cal H}) \not \subset D(B)$, which is generally false also if $D(B)$ is dense.

Comment: Hi, I have understood! Let me think about...

Comment: I filled the gap in my proof, I think. Thanks for your remark I completely missed that point.

Comment: Now also the second remark is not important, because in general $\mathrm{Ran}(P)$ may be infinite dimensional, and thus it is possible that $P^{\perp}(\mathcal{H})\not\subset D(B)$. The proof seems ok now, and the argument is nice!